# Make old Skype work (7.*, 6.*, 5.* or older)

Tags: windows-7, skype, version

I would like the old Skype to start working again.

I really really need it, and I've been trying to make it work for 3 months now, but all to no avail.. Maybe there is some enthusiast who can make the old version of Skype work?

By the old version of Skype, I mean anything older than version 8. That would be cool!

Comment: What is in V8 that stops you from using it. Not much difference that i can see.  I have Skype V8 on Windows 11 Pro.

Comment: You could try the procedure described in [How to run older versions of Skype for Windows](http://www.skaip.org/how-to-run-older-versions-of-skype-for-windows), although it's from 2017 and may not work.

Comment: “I would like the old Skype to start working again.” - What you want is impossible. Since Skype requires communicating with a server, they can reject older versions, and in fact that’s exactly what Microsoft has done.

Answer (score 1):

#### I would like the old Skype to start working again.

It is not possible.

> **Support for Skype versions 7 and below is ending**
>
> Support for Skype versions 7 and below will end on November 1, 2018 on
> desktop devices and November 15, 2018 on mobile and tablet devices.
>
> What does end of support mean for me?
>
> Microsoft will no longer provide security updates or technical support
> for Skype versions 7 and below. **If you are still using an older
> version, you must update to the latest version to continue using
> Skype**.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Source: [Support for Skype versions 7 and below is ending | Skype Support](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34864/support-for-skype-versions-7-and-below-is-ending)

Comment: Not only that, but Skype itself may not last too much longer. Teams & Zoom have just about killed it off. It's not even in Win 11 at all by default. It's been relegated to the app store.